# How to get the nearest ancestor or child of an ancestor with xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Look at `<bookmark/>`. The desired output I want is the id with value `5`

`<xsl:value-of select="//bookmark/ancestor::*[@id][1]/@id"/>` only gives me `4`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
   <section id="1">
        <section id="2"/>
        <section id="3"/>
        <section id="9"/>
    </section>
    <section id="4">
        <section>
            <section id="10"/>
            <section id="5"/>
            <section>
                <bookmark/>
                <section id="6">
                    <section id="7">
                        <section id="8"/>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </section>
    </section>
</content>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the only correct answer at present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The way I understand the question and the provided XML document is that the nearest `id` attribute can also happen on an ancestor (`section`) element**.

In any such case the expressions using ony the `preceding::` axis (as specified in the other answers to this question) don't select any node.

**One correct XPath expression, which selects the wanted `id` attribute is**:

```
    (//bookmark/ancestor::*[@id][1]/@id 
| 
    //bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id
     )
     [last()]
```

If the `id` attribute is also allowed on the `bookmark` element itself, the above XPath expression needs to be modified slightly to accomodate this:

```
    (//bookmark/ancestor-or-self::*[@id][1]/@id 
| 
    //bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id
     )
     [last()]
```

**Do note:** The `ancestor::` and the `preceding::` axes do not intersect (do not overlap).

Answer (score 5):

`section[@id=5]` is not an ***ancestor*** of `<bookmark>`, but it is ***preceding*** it.

> The **ancestor** axis contains the
>   ancestors of the context node; the
>   ancestors of the context node consist
>   of the parent of context node and the
>   parent's parent and so on; thus, the
>   ancestor axis will always include the
>   root node, unless the context node is
>   the root node
>
> The **preceding** axis contains all nodes
>   in the same document as the context
>   node that are before the context node
>   in document order, excluding any
>   ancestors and excluding attribute
>   nodes and namespace nodes

Change `ancestor::` to `preceding::`:

```
//bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id
```

Comment: Mads Hansen: This solution doesn't cover the case in which the nearest element with an `id` attribute is the parent or an ancestor. See my answer for a correct XPath expression that covers also this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use the preceding axis:

```xml
<xsl:value-of select="//bookmark/preceding::*[@id][1]/@id"/>
```