# Xpath / Getting the most close ancestor with some value

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to get the most close ancestor of a `WebElement` with some attribute.

For example:

```
<div>
    <i value1= "hello">
       <a value1 = "bye">
          <div id="2"> Hello </div></a></i></div>
```

I have a `WebElment` in `Jave` that presents the `div (id="2")`

How I can get the most close parent which have the `value1` attribute?

In this case, I would get the element `a` with `value1="bye"`.

I try the next: `divElement.findElement(By.xpath("/ancestor-or-self::*[@value1]"));` but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a relative XPath expression, i.e. starting with `./` not `/`:

```
divElement.findElement(By.xpath("./ancestor-or-self::*[@value1][1]"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554488/how-to-get-the-nearest-ancestor-or-child-of-an-ancestor-with-xpath). I believe thats what you need

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='2']/preceding::*[@value1][1]"));
```

That said, I am not sure why you have a need to do this. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: This is just plain wrong. Not all preceding elements are on the ancestor axis (thus "parents"). Additionally, scanning for `<bookmark/>` elements does not help at all.

Comment: The question asks for immediate parent. `preceding` will give the next ancestor. `<bookmark>` thing was an error on my part which I corrected

Comment: No it doesn't. What if there is a `preceding-sibling` with `@value` just between the parent and current node?